# Postgresql regular expression in type rather than check constraint

Tags: postgresql, types

This question is loosely based off [How can I create a constraint to check if an email is valid in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689718/how-can-i-create-a-constraint-to-check-if-an-email-is-valid-in-postgres)

I know I can use a string type and constrain it via a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
  email varchar
  CONSTRAINT proper_email CHECK (email ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$')
```

);

However, I'd like to be able to create a custom type so that the syntax would be the following

```
create table emails (
    email email_address
);
```

I would have thought that [CREATE TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtype.html) would be of use here but since this is not a composite, range nor enum type, I'm not sure how I'd approach it.

For the record, this is because I have multiple tables all with the same check constraint. I'd like to tweak the constraint in one spot (via a type perhaps) rather than go through all the tables one by one. I think it could also make the table definitions look a lot nicer (it's not for emails, but it's directly appliable if it were solved for an "email_address" type).

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtype.html) says you can autobox a string to a certain type using an input and output function. Perhaps if I raise an exception upon receipt of an invalid cstring it could be made to work that way, but it seems like a sledgehammer especially considering I do still want it to be a string after all; just a little syntactic sugar/de-duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [domain.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)

```
create domain email_address as text
    check (value ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$')
```

Examples:

```
select 'abc'::email_address;

ERROR:  value for domain email_address violates check constraint "email_address_check"

select 'abc@mail.com'::email_address;

 email_address 
---------------
 abc@mail.com
(1 row)
```

Comment: That's about as perfect an answer as I could have hoped for. Thanks!