# Postgres trigger cannot insert value which contains a number or special char

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I would like to ask you for help with my function. I would like to make a trigger before insert.If someone want to insert name which contains number or special character it will not be able. The valid value only can contains a-zA-Z letters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_control_value()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.name LIKE ‘%[a-zA-Z]%’ and NEW.surname LIKE‘%[a-zA-Z]%’ THEN 
   return new;
ELSE
   RAISE WARNING ‘INVALID CHARACTERS IN ENTERING VALUE';
   Return null;
END IF;
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a constraint to check if an email is valid in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689718/how-can-i-create-a-constraint-to-check-if-an-email-is-valid-in-postgres)

Comment: You are looking for a CHECK constraint for each field, not a trigger. Your `LIKE` expression won't prevent non-letter characters anyway, they match any string that contains at least one letter, even eg `123A%^*&`

Comment: Try something like `CONSTRAINT proper_name CHECK (name ~* '[^A-Za-z]'), CONSTRAINT proper_surname (surname ~* '[^A-Za-z]')`

Comment: I would like to make a trigger on insert. When someone want to insert values which contains digit or special character the trigger will execute and show warning raise.

Comment: That's what CHECK constraints are about.  In any case, you need to check for values that contain non-letters. You need to invert the `IF` statement and either use the regular expression in the trigger or use `LIKE '[^A-Za-z]'`

Comment: *Why* do you want to use a trigger? A CHECK constraint is part of the schema, it's where people expect to find such ... checks. The query processor can use them to quickly discard values it knows will never appear in the field and generate better execution plans

Comment: I understand that it is not logical to do trigger on that when i can make constraint, but it must be solved with trigger.

Comment: Invert the condition then. Write `IF NEW.name LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]' OR NEW.surname LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]’ THEN  RAISE WARNING ‘INVALID CHARACTERS IN ENTERING VALUE'; ...`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name never said it does nor posted code that suggest this. I wrote that if LIKE is used, the pattern should be `LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]'` to catch values that contain anything *but* letters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes you did: `LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]'`LIKE does **not** support patterns like that. The only wildcards it supports is `%` form multiple characters and `_` for a single character: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it does. That's not a regular expression, that's one of the very few patterns that LIKE can handle

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: read the manual. `LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]'` is **exactly** the same thing as `= '[^a-zA-Z]'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name (facepalm) that's what I get for trying to answer questions while debugging queries in other databases at 9pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only wildcards that `LIKE` supports are `%` form multiple characters and `_` for a single character.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

> If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like the equals operator. An underscore (`_`) in pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (`%`) matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

So, `LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'` simply means: any value that contains the string `[a-zA-z]` somewhere

For example, the following query:

```
select 'foobar' LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%' as one,
       'this [a-zA-Z] matches' LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%' as two;
```

returns

```
one   | two 
------+-----
false | true
```

If you want to match against a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), you need to use `~` or `SIMILAR TO`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_control_value()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.name ~ '^[a-zA-Z]*$' and NEW.surname ~ '^[a-zA-Z]*$' THEN 
     return new;
   ELSE
     RAISE WARNING 'INVALID CHARACTERS IN ENTERING VALUE';
     Return null;
   END IF;
END;
$function$;
```

---

But rather then silently (!) ignoring the insert or update, I would throw an exception that will show up as an error to the session that did the insert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_control_value()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.name ~ '^[a-zA-Z]*$' and NEW.surname ~ '^[a-zA-Z]*$' THEN 
     return new;
   ELSE
     RAISE 'Only characters from A to Z allowed!';
   END IF;
END;
$function$;
```

Note that you have to use that in a `BEFORE` trigger, otherwise this does not work.

```
create trigger ugly_check_constraint_trigger()
    BEFORE insert or update on the_table
    for each row 
    execute procedure fnc_control_value();
```

---

But again: this is better done with a check constraint.