# SQL join two tables by modifying on columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables on PostgreSQL:

SPENDINGS:

```
store      |spending
-----------+---------
0000700551 |   $75
```

STORE:

```
store  | zip_code
-------+---------
700551 | XXP PDD
```

CUSTOMER:

```
id  | zip_code
----+----------
002 | XXPPDD
```

I would love to join these tables like this:

```
right(SPENDIGNS.store, 6) = STORE.store and     
trim(STORE.zip_code) = CUSTOMER.zip_code.
```

How can I do that could you help me out please?

Comment: Having to clean your data during a join means that indexes will not be used.  Clean your data and write queries for clean, indexed data.  Don't write queries for dirty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim(store.zip_code)` is not good for the job because the whitespace is within the zip code text. Use `replace(store.zip_code, ' ', '')` instead. `right(spendings.store, 6)` does not seem safe to me too. Better use `ltrim(spendings.store, '0')` to remove leading zeroes. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c56d4/5)

```sql
select * 
  from spendings sp 
  join store st on ltrim(sp.store, '0') = st.store
  join customer cu on cu.zip_code = replace(st.zip_code, ' ', '');
```

BTW your data design does need improvement.

Comment: It works Stefanov. Thank you.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do to improve it?

Comment: A few hints. Make `spendings.store` and `store.store` integers, `spendings.spending` numeric and try to set a pattern (the same) for `store.zip_code` and `customer.zip_code`. This will allow you to use indexes if necessary. Have a look at the comment of @MatBailie.

Comment: Thanks Stefanov. Should I do it beforehand. You mean i need to create patterns(stadartize) it before query?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would suggest to standardize zip codes upon insert. Adding a check constraint on zip code fields that enforces pattern compliance would be the best. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689718/how-can-i-create-a-constraint-to-check-if-an-email-is-valid-in-postgres) SO post will help you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try something as follows (you can use what ever join you would like to in place of inner)

```
select spendings.spending, store.store,customer.zipcode 
from spendings inner join store on right(SPENDIGNS.store, 6) = STORE.store 
inner join customer on trim(STORE.zip_code) = CUSTOMER.zip_code
```

Comment: That doesn't even run.  You can't `INNER JOIN ON`, you need a table name between `JOIN` and `ON`; ***both*** joins are missing the tables being joined on.